# Cost of a Session call?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, performance, session

When wrapping my Session variables in Page Properties, does it make sense to save the value into a local variable and prefer to call the value from there?

```
private Foo MySessionFoo
{
    get
    {
        if (_localFoo == null)
            _localFoo = Session["MySessionFoo"] as Foo;
        return _localFoo;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["MySessionFoo"] = _localFoo = value;
    }
}
```

Assuming I use InProc Session Mode and not SQL-based, does it make any noticable difference or does the additional saving and checking actually hurt my performance more than it helps?

Should I rather do

```
private Foo MySessionFoo
{
    get
    {
        return Session["MySessionFoo"] as Foo;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["MySessionFoo"] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be more efficient and future-proof to use a local variable/caching.  However, the different will not be huge unless you're accessing it for example tens or hundreds of times IMO.

Can I suggest:

```
return this._localFoo ?? (this._localFoo = Session["MySessionFoo"] as Foo);
```

The `this` is optional, but this is a little neater, again just IMO.

Note: nice use of the coalesce operator `??` and the fact that the `result` of an assignment expression is the same as the value being assigned.

Comment: Will work fine if you access the variable during the same post-back, otherwise the lookup will be performed every time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much difference we can find as both are executed in server side.

IF possible, we should avoid using Session itself. :)

Comment: Also, you should explain why we should avoid using the session so we can better tell why you're wrong/right.